# MySQL: I need more than two OR conditions! How can I do that?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am quite a beginner with mySql and I am facing a problem. 
I am creating a search bar and I want to select an item from a database whenever the keyword match with the color, the brand etc...

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT title, description, picture FROM clothes 
        WHERE type LIKE :keyword;
        OR color LIKE :keyword;
        OR brand LIKE :keyword;
        OR material LIKE :keyword";
```

So far I can only find items from the type request... The color, brand etc are not working.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have semicolons at the end of the lines within the query.  Remove them:

```
$sql - "SELECT title, description, picture
        FROM clothes 
        WHERE type LIKE :keyword OR
              color LIKE :keyword OR
              brand LIKE :keyword OR
              material LIKE :keyword";
```

Comment: ...the reason being that the semicolon is the default statement terminator.